# How to apply pivot table query properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have that table as follows

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE DriversTask (
Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
FromTime time(7) NOT NULL,
ToTime time(7) NOT NULL,
AtDate date,
Driver varchar(200),
);


INSERT INTO DriversTask ([FromTime],[ToTime],[AtDate],[Driver])
VALUES
('02:30:00','03:40:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('04:50:00','05:10:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('05:40:00','06:00:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('06:30:00','07:15:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('07:40:00','08:00:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('09:48:00','10:40:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('11:12:00','12:40:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('13:00:00','14:00:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('15:30:00','17:40:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('19:50:00','21:22:00', '2022-08-23', 1),
('22:30:00','00:00:00', '2022-08-23', 1);
```

I need to show data as follows

```
Driver 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24

1     [  --- ---- ---- --- ----  ---- ---- ----- ----- ---- ---- ----] ...etc
```

That means driver 1 has tasks during the day hours where it meets the column [FromTime]

I have tried to apply SQL pivot but I don't know where is the problem

```
SELECT [Driver], [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24] FROM   
(SELECT [Driver], TimeFrom, TimeTo FROM DriversTask ) Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(TimeFrom) FOR Driver 
IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24])
) AS Tab2
```

Comment: You probably gets error on invalid column name `TimeFrom`, `TimeTo`. The column name in the table is `FromTime` and `ToTime`

Comment: After you fix the column name problem you should gets error on `SUM(TimeFrom)`. You can't perform `SUM` on `TIME` data type

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM   
(SELECT [Driver], FromTime,[Driver] AS DriverName FROM #DriversTask ) Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
MAX(FromTime) FOR [Driver] 
IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24])
) AS Tab2
```

Please check the above query. Fixed three issues,

1. ColumnName mismatch
2. Used MAX instead of SUM since SUM can't be used with Date Column.
   3)Included Driver column in Select list with a alias name.

Comment: thanks for answer. however, it gives me that result as not expected [Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WKGZYn4xBUhDjivTT_az5f_N9AaX-pLC/view?usp=sharing). All columns are empty

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?